# JPA Repository findAll returns empty list

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I am trying to fetch a list from database and findAll() returns empty list.
I have multiple jpa repositories but only one does not work. This is the code:

```
@Repository
public interface ProductCategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<ProductCategory,Integer> {
}
```

and this is the entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ProductCategory {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "productCategory", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

When I call productCategoryRepository.findAll() it returns empty list thus I have many entries in the database.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: You could add Product entity mapping.

Comment: I have it. It works if i have @JsonIgnore above productCategory

Comment: Show the piece of code where you are returning the list and are trying to display/use it. Very highly likely chances are, you are not populating the list properly.

Comment: @Autowired
        private ProductCategoryRepository productCategoryRepository;
    
    
    @GetMapping("/categs")
        List<ProductCategory> findCategs(){
            return productCategoryRepository.findAll();
        }

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem I solved generating the getters & setters because I didn't have configured my lombok